# Check an array for non-numeric characters

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a function that will check an array for non-numeric characters. I'm sure there is a way with existing functions, but I was hoping to make a clean function.

This is what I have:

```
Public Function ContainsAllNumbers(Text() As Variant) As Boolean

    For Each element In Text

        If Not IsNumeric(element) Then

            ContainsAllNumbers = False

        End If

    Next

End Function
```

The arguments I want it to take would be something like 11013688 or K03778 or 9005110-4400. I need to know if these strings contain something that is not a number.

Comment: Use the [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365(v=vs.60).aspx) and loop from [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) to [UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your description is ambiguous -- is your function supposed to accept an *array* (which is what you actually describe the input as) or a *string* (which is what your example input is). Also -- what would the return value for input `9005110-4400` be? True -- it just contains two number, or Fasle -- it contains the nonnumeric character `-`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should be more clear. The error was that excel kept saying "#VALUE." And the goal is to be able to put in something like "K03778" and have it return false. It should return true for "1111" because it contains all numbers.

Comment: The error that you got was due to trying to pass a string as an array. In VBA strings are not arrays and you can't loop through them with a for-each loop like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a (debugged) function which takes a string input and returns `True` if and only if all of the characters in the string are digits. This is (perhaps) what you are trying to do:

```
Function AllDigits(s As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) Then
            AllDigits = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    AllDigits = True
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Apologies for the confusion. I was intent upon figuring it out myself, but I had never used VBA. I really appreciate your help, as well as everyone else's.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want a function that takes an array of strings and checks them for nun-numeric values. Then your question would be, why your function always returns `False`.

The default value of a `Boolean` is false so you need to set `ContainsAllNumbers = True` at the beginning of the function.

I also recommend using `Option Explicit` so you don't forget to `Dim` your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the characters to their ascii code and check each of them. You can Look up an ascii table to find out the specific values for certain characters.

As an example I just copied this from one of my macros. It checks for non-alphanumeric values in the input string str:

```
invalidCharacter = false
For pos = 1 To Len(str) 
Select Case Asc(Mid(str, pos, 1)) 'ascii value of character at str(pos)
        Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122 '0-9,a-z,A-Z
            'nothing
        Case Else
            invalidCharacter = True
    End Select
Next pos
If invalidCharacter Then
    MsgBox "only numbers or letters may be used"
End If
```